# Accessing the value of an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

Getting stuck with the indexing problem in php codeigniter. I am trying to access the value of the key .

```
array(1) 
{ 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#20 (11) 
    { 
        ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["user_id"]=> string(2) "49" 
        ["username"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["first_name"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["last_name"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["u_id"]=> string(1) "6"
    }
}
```

Here i am trying to get the value of the `"u_id" by`$u_array->u_id` but getting error.

Comment: you seem to have an array of objects, maybe try `$u_array[0]->u_id`

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have to reference the key of the object stored in the array.

```
$u_array[0]->u_id
```